# Run time error in Castalia

Tags: omnet++

Hey friends i had installed Omnet++ 4.2.2 and Castalia 3.2.I had tried to run the example simulations,but it saying an run time error.i had attached it as a image.Please help me.Please tell me the solutions.Help indeed please.

[image: Error in Castalia]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can I suggest you list the error test in your message as well, to make it easier for people to understand whether they can assist. You might also mention what you have tried so far...

Comment: Hello Sir.Yes Sir.I want to make Cluster of nodes in Castalia.I am an Amateur to omnet++. I had imported Castalia 3.2 and just i had run the simulation->radiotest->omnetpp.ini. I got the error which i had attached previously. Can u help me please to resolve this error and to make cluster of nodes in castalia.

Comment: castalia and omnet work better under linux, you might consider using a linux machine for your simulations. for extra information you can refer to the official documentations: https://castalia.forge.nicta.com.au/index.php/en/documentation.html

Comment: Oh well Thank You.I had installed it and run those tic tac tutorials.Its working good.Can you guide me how to make a cluster in castalia?

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't build the Castalia. In order to build it under Windows do the following:

1. Open in any text editor the file `makemake` from main `Castalia-3.2` directory, and change the line: 
   `OPTS=" -f -r --deep -o CastaliaBin -u Cmdenv -P $ROOT -M release"` 
    into: 
   `OPTS=" -f -r --deep -P $ROOT -M release"`
2. Open console `mingwenv.cmd`.
3. Change directory to the Castalia directory. Example: assuming that `Castalia-3.2` is in `d:\Castalia-3.2` you should type:
    `cd /d/Castalia-3.2`
4. Then type in `mingwcmd` console: 
    
   `./makemake`
   `make`
5. In order to check it try to start a simulation by typing in console:
   `cd Simulations/BANtest/`
   `../../Castalia-3.2.exe`
   The simulation should start in graphical mode.